# Remove Duplicate Function with LookupSet returing #Error in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In my `SSRS` Report, I am using `LOOKUPSET` function to `concatenate` one of the `field values` . In-order to get `distinct concatenated` values I used `RemoveDuplicates` Vb Function in Report Code.

the `function` code is:

```
Public Shared Function RemoveDuplicates(ByVal items As Object())  As String()
System.Array.Sort(items)
Dim k As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To items.Length - 1
If i > 0 AndAlso items(i).Equals(items(i - 1)) Then
Continue For
End If
items(k) = items(i)
k += 1
Next
Dim unique As [String]() = New [String](k - 1) {}
System.Array.Copy(items, 0, unique, 0, k)
Return unique
End Function
```

My TextBox `Expression` is,

```
=Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookUpSet(Fields!id.Value,
Fields!id.Value,
Fields!code.Value,
"ds_DataSet1")), " , ")
```

This `expression` works fine in all the cases except `blanks`.If `Fields!code.Value` contain only blanks, Report Preview Returns the error `#Error` in the `field value`.

When I removed the `RemoveDuplicates` function from the `expression`, it works fine for all the cases. Do I need to make changes in the `vb function` to incorporate blanks also? what I am missing here?

Comment: Do you need the blanks or could you just remove them before you run your code?

Comment: By blank I meant the column having no data

Comment: yes, i'm assuming you mean Fields!code.Value = nothing

Comment: Yes.. exactly. The function throws error if all the values are blank

Comment: What would the expected input to the code look like?

Comment: The values are text data type. I convert them html tags for concatenation. For this error scenario. The input is just a blank value

Comment: So all values are going in as blank? or just some?

Comment: The error thrown when all values are blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, make following changes to your code:

change the function as following: (null/nothing values will be then converted to empty string '')

```
Public Shared Function RemoveDuplicates(ByVal items As Object())  As String()

For j As Integer = 0 To items.Length - 1
If j > 0  Then
Continue For
End If
if(items(j) is nothing) then
items(j) = ""
End If
Next


System.Array.Sort(items)
Dim k As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To items.Length - 1
If i > 0 AndAlso items(i).Equals(items(i - 1)) Then
Continue For
End If
items(k) = items(i)
k += 1
Next
Dim unique As [String]() = New [String](k - 1) {}
System.Array.Copy(items, 0, unique, 0, k)
Return unique
End Function
```

modify expression to remove empty string :

```
=Replace(
 Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(
 LookUpSet(Fields!id.Value, Fields!id.Value, Fields!code.Value,"ds_DataSet1")
 ), " , ")
 , ",  ,", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle blank field update your Shared Function code as below:

```
Public Shared Function RemoveDuplicates(ByVal items As Object())  As String()
System.Array.Sort(items)
Dim k As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To items.Length - 1
    If i > 0 AndAlso items(i) <> "" AndAlso items(i).Equals(items(i - 1)) Then
        Continue For
    End If
    items(k) = items(i)
    k += 1
Next
Dim unique As [String]() = New [String](k - 1) {}
System.Array.Copy(items, 0, unique, 0, k)
Return unique
End Function
```

Also, update the Textbox expression to remove the empty string as

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookupSet(
    Fields!id.Value,
Fields!id.Value,
Fields!code.Value,
"ds_DataSet1"))(0)), "", 
Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookUpSet(
Fields!id.Value,
Fields!id.Value,
Fields!code.Value,
"ds_DataSet1")), " , "))
```

Cheers,
Kirti Singh | Soluzione IT Services

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and turns out it was due to incompatibility between output of LookupSet and the custom function. I resolved it using CStr() on the output of LookupSet function and both of its inputs.

This resolved my problem.